# Flutter read mutiple SIM card number

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, flutter-dependencies, sim-card

Using mobile_number package to detect multiple SIM card but only able to detect 1 sim card in few android and in few android not able to detect even 1 SIM card, and also need help with which sim is detected SIM1 or SIM2

```
@override
  void onInit() {
    dbtIdController.value.addListener(dbtFormValid);
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      MobileNumber.listenPhonePermission((isPermissionGranted) {
        if (isPermissionGranted) {
          initMobileNumberState();
        }
      });
      initMobileNumberState();
    }
    super.onInit();
  }
```

```
Future<void> initMobileNumberState() async {
    if (!await MobileNumber.hasPhonePermission) {
      await MobileNumber.requestPhonePermission;
      return;
    }
    List<SimCard> simCards = [];
    try {
      (await MobileNumber.mobileNumber)!;
      List<SimCard> simCardList = (await MobileNumber.getSimCards)!;
      simCards = simCardList;
      availableMobileNumbers.clear();
      for (var simCard in simCards) {
        String mobileNumber = simCard.number ?? 'N/A';
        availableMobileNumbers.add(mobileNumber);
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Failed to get SIM cards because of ${e.message}');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Been facing this issue and we need to implement a two way scenario for higher and lower android sdks to solve this in the long run

```
 // For newer SDKs, use SubscriptionManager, for older, use TelephonyManager directly
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        // Use SubscriptionManager APIs for newer versions
    } else {
        // Use TelephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber(), etc. for older versions
    }

    return simCardNumbers;
}
```

}